# Merging these two if... else statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, I'm new to jQuery. So I have this jQuery code with two if else statement, which I want to merge 'cause I feel it's an unnecessary repetition. They are somewhat different codes, since once is acting on `ul#tabs li a` and the other on `ul.tabs li a`. How can I merge them to improve performance?  Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var hash = location.hash;

    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content

    if ($("ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']").length) 
    { 
        $("ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']")
            .addClass("active")
            .parent()
            .addClass("active"); //Activate tab

        $(hash).show();
    }
    else 
    {
        do stuff
    }  

    if ($("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']").length) 
    {
        $("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']")
            .addClass("active")
            .parent()
            .addClass("active"); //Activate tab

        $(hash).show();
    }
    else 
    {
        do stuff
    }  
});
```

How do I merge these two codes?

Comment: could you simply add the class 'tabs' to the element with the id "#tabs" and only run the first if/else statement?

Comment: are both "do stuff"s the same code? btw for performance, you are running the same selectors twice (once for the ifs and once again for the class add), you should just run each selector once and save into a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma operator, `,`, is used in CSS and jQuery to specify multiple selectors:

```
    var sel = $("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "'], ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']");
    if (sel.length) { 
        sel.addClass("active").parent().addClass("active"); //Activate tab
        $(hash).show();
    }
    else {
        do stuff
    }
```

You can reduce duplication even further:

```
var sel = $("ul.tabs, ul#tabs").find("li a[href='" + hash + "']");
....
```

Comment: wow! dude you're amazing. One problem though. It has that link jumping effect. `e.preventDefault()`; should do the magic right?

Answer (score 2):

[You could utilize multiple selectors with a comma](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
if ($("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "'], ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "'] ").length) {
```

For your case you could go with the `each()` method:

```
var el = $("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "'], ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']");

if(el.length) {
    el.each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active").parent().addClass("active");
        $(hash).show();
    }); 
} else {
   // do else stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks very much bro. Same answer. Just that his came first ;).. Do you by chance know I can prevent that link jumping effect?

Comment: @JoePaul Add an event variable inside of the callback definition: `el.each(function(evt) {` then after calling `$(hash).show();` do `evt.preventDefault()`. Either that, or simply `return false;`